# Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in Mypro.exe

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, managed-c++

I have a `MCVC++ 2010` MFC project that accesses a third party C DLL with 4functions.
I got the DLL working fine with a Win32 project in Visual Studio 2010. But when I integrate it into my MFC project that works perfectly fine, I get this

`"Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error"` the moment I try to access a function from this DLL. I get no useful info in the call stack or the Output console. 
Just after the function call the control lands in debughook.c,
 at the very end `_debugger_hook_dummy = 0;`

**dbghook.c**

```
int __cdecl _CrtDefaultAllocHook(int nAllocType,void * pvData, size_t nSize,int nBlockUse, long lRequest,const unsigned char * szFileName, int nLine )
{
return 1; /* allow all allocs/reallocs/frees */
}

#endif  /* _DEBUG */

int _debugger_hook_dummy;

#ifdef _M_IA64
#undef _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK
#define _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK __crt_debugger_hook
#endif  /* _M_IA64 */

__declspec(noinline)
void __cdecl _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK(int _Reserved)
{
    /* assign 0 to _debugger_hook_dummy so that the function is not folded in retail */
    (_Reserved);
    _debugger_hook_dummy = 0;
}
```

The code is enclosed in `try-catch`, but when I try to step-in the control never reaches the catch block. No clear indicator of where the problem lies. Any pointers?